# gluCylinder vs glutSolidCylinder

Tags: opengl, freeglut, glu

Though I know gluCylinder is somewhat old(and glu too) and glut is still there(through freeglut) but I saw those two and wondering what's the difference ? besides that gluCylinder requires that you define a Quadric, and what's faster ? .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original GLUT did not have a `glutSolidCylinder()` function. That appears to be something FreeGLUT added.

### `gluCylinder`

Pros:

- Supports texture coordinate generation.

Cons:

- GLU is **old**. I mean, **really really old**. The spec was last updated in 1998, and I suspect that the available implementations are just as old. This means that it's using immediate mode rendering (`glBegin`/`glEnd`) style, which is inefficient, and not available anymore in modern versions of OpenGL.
- GLU support is starting to disappear from some platforms.

### `glutSolidCylinder`

Pros:

- As long as you're comfortable with using FreeGLUT, it's still supported, with source code available.
- The FreeGLUT version seems to be able to use moderately modern rendering methods (VBOs), based on browsing the [source code](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/git_master/freeglut/freeglut/src/fg_geometry.c).

Cons:

- Does not generate texture coordinates. This was definitely not supported for most solids in GLUT, and as far as I can tell is still not supported for cylinders in FreeGLUT.

### self-made

Rendering a cylinder is very easy. Personally, I would just write it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Reto. I prefer implementing a cylinder myself too. Specially because it has a simple parametric form (a stack of circles). Interestingly, I was helping somebody else to dray cylinders. Maybe you find that interesting too:

[Make a line thicker in 3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30361562/make-a-line-thicker-in-3d/30363830#30363830)