# Make a line thicker in 3D?

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, scenekit

In reference to this question

> [Drawing a line between two points using SceneKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886224/drawing-a-line-between-two-points-using-scenekit)

I'm drawing a line in 3D and want to make it thicker by using this code

```
  func renderer(aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, willRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: NSTimeInterval) {
    //Makes the lines thicker
    glLineWidth(20)
  }
```

but it doesn't work, iOS 8.2.

Is there another way?

***Update***

From the docs

> https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRendererDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNSceneRendererDelegate/renderer:updateAtTime:

I did add `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` and a valid line width but still could not get the line width to increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign any number to `glLineWidth()`.
You can check the range of possible values of `glLineWidth()`by:

```
glGetFloatv(GL_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE,sizes);
```

One crazy idea is to use a cylinder for drawing lines ;). I use it when I want to have nice and controllable lines but I am not aware of a handy OpenGl function to do so.

Comment: thanks for that. do you have a func for cylinder that accepts two points and puts cylinder there?

Comment: I think I do... Let me go and eat dinner I would be back in 2 hours ;)

Answer (score 2):

@G Alexander: here you go my implementation of cylinder. It is a bit tedious but it is what I have at the moment.
If you give me points `p0` and `p1`, Vector `normal=(p1-p0).normalize()` would be the axis of the cylinder.
pick point p2 that is not on the vector Normal.

```
q=(p2-p0).normalize();
normal.crossproduct(q)=v0;
normal.crossproduct(v0)=v1;
```

Having these two vectors you can have circles with any radius that are stacked along the axis of the cylinder using the following function (A cylinder is a stack of circles):

```
public Circle make_circle(Point center, Vector v0, Vector v1, double radius)
        {
            Circle c;
            for (double i = 0; i < 2 * Math.PI; i += 0.05)
            {
                Point p = new Point(center + radius * Math.Cos(i) * v0 + radius * Math.Sin(i) * v1);
                c.Add(p);
            }
          return c;
        }
```

You only need to make circles using this function along the axis of the cylinder:

```
List<Circle> Cylinder = new List<Circle>();
for(double i=0;i<1;i+=0.1)
{
  Cylinder.add( make_circle(P0+i*normal, v0, v1,radius);

}
```

Now you should take two consecutive circles and connect them with quads by sampling uniformly.

I have implemented it this way since I had circles implemented already.

A simpler way to implement is make the circle along the x axis and then rotate and translate it to `p0` and make it align with normal or to use gluCylinder if you are the fan of Glu....

Hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Thanks!! I can make this work, I thought initially you were using the primitive SCNCylinder and couldn't figure out how you were going to do the math of  the angles.

Comment: :)))) sometimes I am obsessed to my crazy ways of doing things